# Get MAX() on repeating IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is how my query results look like currently. How can I get the MAX() value for each unique id ?

IE,

```
for 5267139 is 8.
for 5267145 is 4

5267136 5
5267137 8
5267137 2
5267139 8
5267139 5
5267139 3
5267141 4
5267141 3
5267145 4
5267145 3
5267146 1
5267147 2
5267152 3
5267153 3
5267155 8


    SELECT DISTINCT st.ScoreID, st.ScoreTrackingTypeID
    FROM ScoreTrackingType stt
    LEFT JOIN ScoreTracking st
    ON stt.ScoreTrackingTypeID = st.ScoreTrackingTypeID
    ORDER BY st.ScoreID, st.ScoreTrackingTypeID DESC
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Can you repost your image, it isn't loading? Better yet, just post the query you're using.

Comment: sorry i didnt know how to add a column resultset in a  table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will partition your table into separate blocks based on the column(s) you specify.  You can then apply an aggregate function (`MAX` in this case) against each of the blocks -- this behavior applies by default with the below syntax:

```
SELECT First_column, MAX(Second_column) AS Max_second_column
FROM Table
GROUP BY First_column
```

EDIT:  Based on the query above, it looks like you don't really need the `ScoreTrackingType` table at all, but leaving it in place, you could use:

```
SELECT st.ScoreID, MAX(st.ScoreTrackingTypeID) AS ScoreTrackingTypeID
FROM ScoreTrackingType stt
    LEFT JOIN ScoreTracking st ON stt.ScoreTrackingTypeID = st.ScoreTrackingTypeID
GROUP BY st.ScoreID
ORDER BY st.ScoreID
```

The `GROUP BY` will obviate the need for `DISTINCT`, `MAX` will give you the value you are looking for, and the `ORDER BY` will still apply, but since there will only be a single `ScoreTrackingTypeID` value for each `ScoreID` you can pull it out of the ordering.

Comment: since i already have the query with an order by above , how can i fit the max on the count with that ? do you suggest table variables

Comment: Youre right. I was having trouble with the MAX on my existing query. Your reworked query works like a charm.

Comment: Makes sense. I was applying the MAX() function the wrong way, and not leveraging group by.